# Python numpy update from 1.6 to 1.8

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, path

I have installed numpy 1.8. But when I do print `numpy.__version__` it says 1.6.

What do I have to change to get python to realize where numpy is? Working on a Mac (10.9). I'm using python 2.7.6.

Edit:

I've tried to delete all my versions of numpy. I did pip uninstall numpy. And then I typed:

python
       import numpy
       print numpy.**version**

and it printed out 1.6.2

I can't delete numpy apparently.

Comment: remove them *all* with pip and/or OS package manager, and then `pip install numpy==1.8`

Comment: did that. still doesn't work. apparently, there is still a version of numpy on my computer but I can't find it.

Comment: Best to use a Python distribution like Canopy or Anaconda

Comment: I had exactly this problem as described on Mac OS X El Capitan.  The mistake I made was I installed numpy via pip, pip3 and through brew install.  Then the Mac decided it wasn't going to allow me to remove any of them!  What fixed it for me was using this command: `easy_install numpy=1.11`.  What that does is install numpy yet again (a 3rd time, on top of the numerous other versions I have), and then updates the soft links so that that this latest installed one the default one.  I find it very irritating that pip, sudo pip can install things and then the operating system makes it un-deletable.

Answer (score 8):

I am running Python 2.7.5 on Mac OS X 10.9.4, and this appears to be some kind of weird bug in how the Macintosh factory-installed version of Python is handling upgraded package installations.

In my case, when I do:

```
sudo pip uninstall numpy
```

it removes the version of numpy installed under

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

However, this does not mean that numpy is fully removed from the system!  There are a second set of "backup" versions of several Python packages installed also at:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

When I install numpy using the `/usr/bin/easy_install` utility that Apple shipped with the OS X system, the latest version (currently at 1.9.0, as of this posting) of numpy is loaded into `Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, just as one would expect, and it correctly precedes the "OS X system default" version of numpy in the module load path so that the latest version of numpy is loaded when I do `import numpy` in Python.  However--and this is the really weird, apparently buggy behavior!--when I uninstall numpy, and instead reinstall using either pip, or by doing:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

on a .tar.gz distribution downloaded directly from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/), the upgraded installation *does not* appear to take precedence in the Python module load path, even though it is also installed under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`!

Anyway, to fix the problem (or rather, I should probably say, to work around the bug, at least on Max OS X), follow this procedure:

1. Uninstall the numpy package from `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` using the method of your choice (`pip uninstall numpy` appeared to work for me)
2. Verify that there is indeed no longer any numpy package still remaining under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`
3. Reinstall numpy using the factory-included `/usr/bin/easy_install`.  Do not use any other alternative method, at least not if you want to use numpy with the Apple factory-installed version of Python 2.7

Alternatively, using a completely different distribution of Python (e.g., Canopy or Anaconda), as one of the other commenters already mentioned, should also work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in the comments that removing with pip and OS package manager didn't work for you.  If you may have used `easy_install` in the first place, also try `easy_install -m` for removal.  If all else fails, you can clobber the files manually (the imports are taken from `sys.path` so the first version found in that list is where the import will come from).

Load up interactive python interpreter and check the physical location of the files:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
'/home/wim/.virtualenvs/xyz/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

This will tell you which directory you need to delete in order to prevent the unwanted version from being imported.

This is a somewhat impolite way to "uninstall" numpy, so use as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have inconsistent version of numpy in two paths

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

and

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

My solution is rename (or delete) the one you don't like (possibly the older version) and symlink the other (the newer version) back to the directory which you deleted numpy folder from.