# Pip doesn’t know where numpy is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pip, python-packaging

Trying to uninstall `numpy`. I tried `pip uninstall numpy`. It tells me that it isn't installed. However, `numpy` is still installed at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy`.

How can I make sure `pip` finds the `numpy` package?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python numpy update from 1.6 to 1.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815841/python-numpy-update-from-1-6-to-1-8)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your pip is the right one for your NumPy install. Check the pip and python locations with:

```
$ which pip
$ which python
```

… these should echo `/usr/bin/pip` and `/usr/bin/python`, respectively (since you are evidently on a Mac). Next, check which NumPy your python interpreter is using:

```
$ python -c 'import numpy; print numpy.__file__'
```

… this should print the library path about which you’re asking (e.g. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc`).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe run **deactivate** if you are running virtualenv?